# Css not impacting html (Flask)

Tags: python, flask

I know many people have already have had the same problem as me, but no matter what I try to do I can´t fix it.

My workspace structure is the following:

```
 project folder:
          -app.py
          -template:
              -blah.html
          -static:
              -styles:
                 -main.css
```

I have even changed the template and static dir

```
TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.abspath('C:/Users/loren/.vscode/Code/Website/templates')
STATIC_PATH = os.path.abspath('C:/Users/loren/.vscode/Code/Website/static')

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=TEMPLATE_PATH, static_folder=STATIC_PATH)
```

and I think I have linked the css in my html head the right way

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ref="{{ url_for('static', 
     filename='styles/main.css') }}"/>
```

My css code should turn the body lightblue but nothing happens no matter how often I cmd + shift + R or F5

```
html{
background-color: lightblue;
}
```

It´s probably just a stupid mistake of mine, but I would still be happy for every answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have a simple typo in your `<link>` tag.  It should use the `href=` attribute for the CSS path, not `ref`.

As some additional tips, rather than hard-coding paths to `template_folder` and `static_folder`, if you already have a `templates/` directory adjacent to `app.py`  (note: `templates/` not `template/`) and likewise a `static/` directory, these are used by default.

Comment: I´m so thankfull for your comment and it finally works. I am sorry that i was so dump and forgot just one fcking letter haha.